# How do I get people to eat from a nutrient paste dispenser?

Tags: rimworld

I am having trouble with food as I have hoppers (directly next to a nutrient paste dispenser) that are filled with food, but when my colonists go to eat they take the food out of the hoppers instead of eating nutrient paste.

I am powering my paste dispenser.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the issue?

Answer (score 1):

**1.)** The hopper must be facing the correct direction. The side of the hopper that must face the dispenser is the wider side without the black line on the texture (the open side).

**2.)** It may simply be a glitch in the AI or a general bug, as the game is early in development - especially when this was asked.